# Which way around do cascading deletes go in a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, cascading-deletes

Using Entity Framework code-first approach.

Suppose I have two entity classes:

```
[Table("Objects")]
public class DbObject : IValidatableObject
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DbObjectProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}

[Table("ObjectProperties")]
public class DbObjectProperty
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Object"), UIHint("Object")]
    public long ObjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual DbObject Object { get; set; }
}
```

Points to note here:

- `DbObject` only has a navigation property, but no column with a foreign key
- `DbObjectProperty` has a navigation property *and* a corresponding column with a foreign key
- It should be obvious that if I delete an object, I want its properties to go with it, but if I delete a single property, I don’t want the entire object to disappear.

In the `OnModelCreating` method for the DB context, up until now I had the following to define the relationship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DbObjectProperty>()
    .HasRequired(op => op.Object)
    .WithMany(obj => obj.Properties)
    .HasForeignKey(op => op.ObjectId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Of course, this means no cascaded deletes will occur. My question is: if I change this to `true`, does that do what I want? Remember if I delete an object, I want its properties to go with it, but if I delete a single property, I don’t want the entire object to disappear.

The auto-generated migration code for this change (from `false` to `true`) is this:

```
DropForeignKey("ObjectProperties", "ObjectId", "Objects");
DropIndex("ObjectProperties", new[] { "ObjectId" });
AddForeignKey("ObjectProperties", "ObjectId", "Objects", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
CreateIndex("ObjectProperties", "ObjectId");
```

I am worried that this seems to imply that deleting a property will delete its associated object. Will it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The direction of Cascading Delete of a relationship in the database is defined by what is the principal (table of the primary/unique key) and what is the dependent (table of the foreign key) of this relationship.

Then, if you delete the principal all dependents which have a foreign key value corresponding to the primary/unique key value of that principal are deleted as well. There is no cascading delete in the direction from dependent to principal.

In your case the principal is `DbObject` and the dependent is `DbObjectProperty` because it is the entity/table with the foreign key.

It would rarely make sense to have a cascading delete the other way around - especially in x-to-many relationships: If you delete a dependent (`DbObjectProperty`) and the principal (`DbObject`) would be deleted automatically, a foreign key constraint would be violated if there is any other dependent refering to the principal which is going to be deleted.

You don't need to worry.

Comment: Rule of thumb is, with cascade delete, if deleting a record breaks foreign key from another record, that dependent record is deleted too.

Comment: So `modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().HasMany(p => p.Children).WithOne(c => c.Parent)` is the same as `modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasOne(c => c.Parent).WithMany(p => p.Children)` (they specify the same relationship)?